# Why do I get so many NA's in my Cox proportional hazards model summary output?

Tags: categorical-data, survival, cox-model, censoring

I have tried to run the following Cox proportional hazards model where the dependent variable is Latency (time to a particular event), Censor denotes whether the event happened or not (1 = Yes, 0 = No) and Temperature (factor: 5 levels) and Species (factor: 2 levels) are the explanatory variables.

```
model.F<-coxph(Surv(Latency, Censor) ~ Temperature + Species + Temperature:Species, data = latency.F)
summary(model.F)
```

Here is the summary output:

```
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(Latency, Censor) ~ Temperature + Species + 
    Temperature:Species, data = latency.F)

  n= 213, number of events= 145 

                            coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z
Temperature23           -0.51853   0.59540  0.38947 -1.331
Temperature26           -1.36045   0.25655  0.35826 -3.797
Temperature29           -2.07796   0.12519  0.41586 -4.997
Temperature32           -1.80938   0.16376  0.42288 -4.279
SpeciesAP               -0.56688   0.56729  0.45176 -1.255
SpeciesHA                     NA        NA  0.00000     NA
Temperature23:SpeciesAP  0.01481   1.01492  0.55838  0.027
Temperature26:SpeciesAP  1.00769   2.73927  0.55162  1.827
Temperature29:SpeciesAP  1.16744   3.21375  0.58622  1.991
Temperature32:SpeciesAP  0.20560   1.22826  0.88734  0.232
Temperature23:SpeciesHA       NA        NA  0.00000     NA
Temperature26:SpeciesHA       NA        NA  0.00000     NA
Temperature29:SpeciesHA       NA        NA  0.00000     NA
Temperature32:SpeciesHA       NA        NA  0.00000     NA
                        Pr(>|z|)    
Temperature23           0.183067    
Temperature26           0.000146 ***
Temperature29           5.83e-07 ***
Temperature32           1.88e-05 ***
SpeciesAP               0.209547    
SpeciesHA                     NA    
Temperature23:SpeciesAP 0.978837    
Temperature26:SpeciesAP 0.067729 .  
Temperature29:SpeciesAP 0.046429 *  
Temperature32:SpeciesAP 0.816770    
Temperature23:SpeciesHA       NA    
Temperature26:SpeciesHA       NA    
Temperature29:SpeciesHA       NA    
Temperature32:SpeciesHA       NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

                        exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95
Temperature23              0.5954     1.6796   0.27752
Temperature26              0.2565     3.8979   0.12712
Temperature29              0.1252     7.9882   0.05541
Temperature32              0.1638     6.1066   0.07149
SpeciesAP                  0.5673     1.7628   0.23403
SpeciesHA                      NA         NA        NA
Temperature23:SpeciesAP    1.0149     0.9853   0.33974
Temperature26:SpeciesAP    2.7393     0.3651   0.92918
Temperature29:SpeciesAP    3.2138     0.3112   1.01864
Temperature32:SpeciesAP    1.2283     0.8142   0.21577
Temperature23:SpeciesHA        NA         NA        NA
Temperature26:SpeciesHA        NA         NA        NA
Temperature29:SpeciesHA        NA         NA        NA
Temperature32:SpeciesHA        NA         NA        NA
                        upper .95
Temperature23              1.2774
Temperature26              0.5177
Temperature29              0.2828
Temperature32              0.3751
SpeciesAP                  1.3751
SpeciesHA                      NA
Temperature23:SpeciesAP    3.0320
Temperature26:SpeciesAP    8.0755
Temperature29:SpeciesAP   10.1392
Temperature32:SpeciesAP    6.9919
Temperature23:SpeciesHA        NA
Temperature26:SpeciesHA        NA
Temperature29:SpeciesHA        NA
Temperature32:SpeciesHA        NA

Concordance= 0.651  (se = 0.024 )
Likelihood ratio test= 42.95  on 9 df,   p=2e-06
Wald test            = 44.88  on 9 df,   p=1e-06
Score (logrank) test = 51.43  on 9 df,   p=6e-08
```

Several of the coefficients have come out as NA's and I am not sure why this is. Would anyone be able to tell me how I can fix this?

Comment: If there are only 2 species, there should only be one coefficient shown for species and only 1 interaction of species with each of the 4 non reference temperatures. Check the data and coding for species.

Comment: A simple cross tabulation of covariate levels can show you areas of data sparsity.